# Change a string within a line from a text file using batch

Tags: string, batch-file, replace

I have text file (saved as *.pm but I assume it does not make any difference as it can be open as a text file). The content of the file looks something like:

```
Header

$VAR1 = {
          'Keywords' => {
                               'X' => '80',
                               'Target_Path' => 'Example_PAth',
                               'Y' => 'File_Path',
                               'X' => '80',
                               'Y' => 'File_Path',
                               'X' => '80',
                               'Y' => 'File_Path',
               sdefkjnhksdf  koijsef ökiljsdf
               sdefkjnhksdf  koijsef ökiljsdf
               sdefkjnhksdf  koijsef ökiljsdf
```

I want to change **Example_PAth** to **Example_PAth_New** using a *.bat file.

For this I have the following code:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

:Variables
set InputFile=OldFileName.pm
set OutputFile=NewFileName.pm
set "_strFind=Example_PAth"
set "_strInsert=Example_PAth_New"

:Replace
>"%OutputFile%" (
  for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%InputFile%") do (
    if "%%A" equ "%_strFind%" (echo %_strInsert%) else (echo %%A)
  )

)
```

### **Problem:** The resulting file is identical to the original one. I assume I am not reading the string properly? Or does anyone have an idea how to fix the code?

***Update:***
I now modified the searched and substituted strings to include the whole line as mentioned by @Squashman. It works perfectly if the searched strings does not include the **>** character. If I keep the **>**, the line is detected properly but it will be replaced by a blank line. Any workaround? PS: I can't omit the > character.

Comment: So you are thinking that `'Target_Path' => 'Example_PAth',` will be equal to `Example_PAth`.  That is essentially what your code is doing.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification. But how can I make it look for the string only?

Comment: There is not any _line_ that is equal to `Example_PAth`, just a _part of a line_. I suggest you to change your `if` line by these two: `set "line=%%A"` and `echo !line:%_strFind%=%_strInsert%!`, and `EnableDelayedExpansion`.

Comment: @Aacini , this has written 'Example_PAth_New' at every single line!

Comment: Did you changed the `setlocal disableDelayedExpansion` line by `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` one as I said in my previous comment?

Comment: You should be using `==` instead of `equ` for your string comparison, most likely with `If`'s `/I` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the original code accordingly to the recommendation I gave 12 hours ago and tested it to prove it works (after the OP said in an ***Update*** 10 hours ago that there is not a solution yet).

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:Variables
set InputFile=OldFileName.pm
set OutputFile=NewFileName.pm
set "_strFind=Example_PAth"
set "_strInsert=Example_PAth_New"

:Replace
>"%OutputFile%" (
   for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%InputFile%") do (
      set "line=%%A"
      echo !line:%_strFind%=%_strInsert%!
   )
)
```

**OutputFile:**

```
Header
$VAR1 = {
          'Keywords' => {
                               'X' => '80',
                               'Target_Path' => 'Example_PAth_New',
                               'Y' => 'File_Path',
                               'X' => '80',
                               'Y' => 'File_Path',
                               'X' => '80',
                               'Y' => 'File_Path',
               sdefkjnhksdf  koijsef ökiljsdf
               sdefkjnhksdf  koijsef ökiljsdf
               sdefkjnhksdf  koijsef ökiljsdf
```

Comment: it worked. I miss interpreted your comment and inserted your suggestion solution within the if action and did not remove the il/else block

Comment: I tried to use your solution with another text file. but it seems it has a problem with `!`. IT deleted all `!` and inserted `ECHO is off.` at some other positions

Comment: I managed to solve the `!`problem. But the `ECHO IS OFF` is still written when `line` is empty